# SVN: Checkout additional Projects from same Directory

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, subclipse

We are using subclipse to check out code. Each project is located in SVN as follows:

```
http://127.0.0.1/svn/app/project001
http://127.0.0.1/svn/app/project002
http://127.0.0.1/svn/app/project003
...
http://127.0.0.1/svn/app/project601
```

All projects are required to be checked out.

This is not a problem when creating a new workspace in eclipse, as all the existing projects can be selected. However, when a new project is created, e.g. `http://127.0.0.1/svn/app/project003a`, it can be easily missed.

Ideally, I would like to highlight all the exusting projects, right click, team synchronise, and have any new projects that have been added (at the level of the existing projects) automatically show in the synchronise view. This currently does not happen (and I understand the reasons why).

Our current solution is to go to SVN Repository Exploring view, and re-checkout everything, and click no whenever eclipses asks to we want to overwrite existing directories. This is an obvious inconvenience, especially with so many projects.

We tried using psf files, to manage the projects to be checked out, but found people forget to update them (myself included...).

Does anyoe have any better suggestions of how to manage this? It does not have to be done via eclipse either, but after experimenting with svn command line I am unsure of a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Are all the projects checked out under the same local folder?

I.e. under `/work/`:

```
work/project001
work/project002
work/project003
...
work/project601
```

Then you can checkout projects parent directory `app` under the name `work`:

```
$ svn co http://127.0.0.1/svn/app/ work/
```

And every time you need to update all your existing project / checkout new projects, run `svn update`:

```
work$ svn update
U existing projects updated
A new projects added
```